# How to draw a presentable tree using CFTree?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tree, core-foundation

I have to draw a presentable tree using `CFTree`. You can see in picture

[image]

The should satisfy all principles stated in [this link](http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/).

The principle are :

Principle 1: The edges of the tree should not cross each other.

Principle 2: All nodes at the same depth should be drawn on the same horizontal line. This helps make clear the structure of the tree.

Principle 3: Trees should be drawn as narrowly as possible.

Principle 4: A parent should be centered over its children.

Principle 5: A subtree should be drawn the same no matter where in the tree it lies.

Principle 6: The child nodes of a parent node should be evenly spaced.

How should I calculate X,Y position of each nodes?

Comment: Did you draw it? If so could you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem recursively.

Without diagrams (which would help a lot!) here goes an *outline* - you need to fill in the details! - of one algorithm for this. The algorithm is being typed directly into the answer - expect errors.

First:

- *Bounding box* a rectangle enclosing the drawing of a (sub)tree.
- *Anchor* as the point that connecting arcs will draw *towards* (part of the arc may be obscured by the drawing of nodes) to connect to the (sub)tree.
- The anchor will be the coordinate origin of the bounding box - so bounding boxes are measurements relative to this point.
- A bounding box may have *children* - bounding boxes for subtrees. The location of each child is relative to the boxes anchor.

Now:

Consider first drawing a single node with no children. Based on your desired size you can determine a bounding box for this single node. You are using circles so the anchor, the (0,0) coordinate origin of the bounding box is at the centre and the bounding box is +/- the radius relative to that. So you have the bounding box's anchor, (0,0), and its size relative to that - say (x minimum, x maximum, y minimum, y maximum) being (-radius, +radius, -radius, +radius). You will probably also wish to store the node's label. So for example for the "L" node in your diagram in total you have a representation (i.e. and object) containing: (0,0), (-radius, +radius, -radius, +radius) & "L".

Now consider drawing a node with a single child. By a recursive call determine the bounding box for the child. Construct a bounding box to enclose the child with your node at the top centre of this box and the child bounding box directly below it. So you have the bounding box's anchor, it's size relative to that, and a single child at an offset from the anchor. So for example for the "H" node above you have: (0,0), (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), "H", 1 child at (xoffset, yoffset), child is (a reference to the object) (0,0), (-radius, +radius, -radius, +radius) & "L".

Now consider drawing a node with 2 children, etc.

A single recursive traversal from the root of your tree, at each node combining the information returned from subtrees, produces a structure describing the layout of your tree. Now draw it!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but for anyone else who googled CFTREE and found this image and is looking for a similar diagram, I can recommend GraphViz as a solution.  I've used it and it's easy and powerful.  From ColdFusion or any other language you can call it via the command line, have it create an image, use that image, then delete the image.  The reason I mention this software is there a whole science (algothrym) behind how to build a diagram like this.  Rather than write it yourself, just use this free software.

To get the data ordered by parent/child, in Oracle you can use the CONNECT BY statement.

Build your string of data then call GraphViz - e.g.,

Then refer to the image

And delete it: